# Selecting one image at time

Tags: javascript, css

this is the code:

```
function select(element){
   element.onclick = function(){
      element.classList.toggle('selected');
  }
}
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('my_class_img')).forEach(select);
```

and this is the css:

```
.selected{
border: 3px solid blue;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The images have the same class named `my_class_img`, how can I do for selecting one img at time (Now i can select more than one img)? Thanks everyone!

Edit: Using the code @epascarello gave to me, my other function (`myfun(i)`) doesn't work anymore:

```
        var src1 = "";
        var img = new Array();
        img[0] = new Image();
        img[0].src = "../images/poggiatesta2.jpg";
        img[1] = new Image();
        img[1].src = "../images/poggiatesta1.JPG";
        img[2] = new Image();
        img[2].src = "../images/poggiatesta3.jpg";
            for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            var imagetag = document.createElement("img");
            var onclick = document.createAttribute("onclick");
            onclick.value = "myfun(" + i + ")";

            var sorc = document.createAttribute("src");
            sorc.value = img[i].src;

            var id = document.createAttribute("id");
            id.value = "my_image" + i;

            var clas = document.createAttribute("class");
            clas.value = "my_image_clas";

            imagetag.setAttributeNode(clas);
            imagetag.setAttributeNode(onclick);
            imagetag.setAttributeNode(sorc);
            imagetag.setAttributeNode(id);
            document.body.appendChild(imagetag);
            }
            function myfun(i) {

                src1 = document.getElementById('my_image' + i).src;

            }
```

Comment: Any help? I'm still stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either keep track of the last selected or loop over all the elements and remove the selected class.

```
var _last = null;
function select(element){
   element.onclick = function(){
      element.classList.toggle('selected');
      if(_last) _last.classList.remove("selected");
      _last = element.classList.contains("selected") ? element : null;
  }
}
```

Or use radio buttons :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! There's just a problem, with the code you gave me, my other function doesn't work anymore: `function myfun(i) { src1 = document.getElementById('my_image' + i).src; }`. Do you know why?

Comment: what other function?

Comment: I wrote it in my comment, it's a function which stores in a variable (`src1`) the selected image src.

Comment: Still have no clue how that relates to your code above.

Comment: If you have 5 minutes, i can tell you about that in chat

Comment: Or you can post the code in the question from the start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105027/discussion-between-francesco-monti-and-epascarello).

Answer (score 2):

I would do like this and skip using script.

```css
input {
  display: none
}

input:checked ~ img {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type='radio' name='sel_img'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/100/100'>
</label>
<label>
  <input type='radio' name='sel_img'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/100/100'>
</label>
<label>
  <input type='radio' name='sel_img'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/100/100'>
</label>
<label>
  <input type='radio' name='sel_img'>
  <img src='http://placehold.it/100/100'>
</label>
```